# Connect to database in sepaerate method of my SqlCommand

Tags: c#, database-connection, return-value, sqlclient

I have a form that checks whether values are in a database before adding them.  Each field is in a different table, and to keep everything clean, I have a `checkExists` method for each field. Is there a way to have a separate method that connects to the database, so that I don't have to connect in every field method?

I'd like to do something like this so that my code is less messy:

```
public void SetConnection()
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = 
        new SqlConnection("user id=[username];" +
        "password=[password];" +
        "server=[server];" +
        "database=[db_name];");

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to Connect");
    } 
}

public Boolean CheckData_Company(string[] items)
{
    Class_DB set_conn = new Class_DB();

    try
    {
        set_conn.SetConnection();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    //check that item does not already exist
    string query_string = "SELECT * FROM CR_Company WHERE ([CompanyName] = @companyName";

    SqlCommand check_Company = new SqlCommand(query_string, set_conn);
    check_Company.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", items[0]);
    int CompanyExist = (int)check_Company.ExecuteScalar();

    if(CompanyExist > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I get a

> local variable set_conn
>   Argument 2: Cannot Convert from Class_DB to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

I understand the error, so what can I do to return the correct value, or do I have to establish a connection within my `CheckData_Comany()` method?

Comment: what is "myConnection" defined as?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898711/data-layer-abstract-factory

Comment: @Rand Random, Ahh good point, i'll remember your comment in future debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `SetConnection` should be returning `SqlConnection` back like:

```
public SqlConnection SetConnection()
{

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=[username];" +
                                            "password=[password];" +
                                            "server=[server];" +
                                            "database=[db_name];");
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to Connect");
    }

    return myConnection;

}
```

and then you can have something like:

```
SqlConnection connection = set_conn.SetConnection();
```

and then pass it in `SqlCommand` constructor as parameter :

```
SqlCommand check_Company = new SqlCommand(query_string, connection);
```

Your complete method implementation would become :

```
public Boolean CheckData_Company(string[] items)
{
    bool Exists = false;
    Class_DB set_conn = new Class_DB();
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    try
    {
        connection = set_conn.SetConnection();

        //check that item does not already exist
        string query_string = "SELECT * FROM CR_Company WHERE ([CompanyName] = @companyName";
        SqlCommand check_Company = new SqlCommand(query_string, set_conn);
        check_Company.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", items[0]);
        int CompanyExist = (int)check_Company.ExecuteScalar();

        if(CompanyExist > 0)
            Exists =  true;


     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
     }
     finally
     {
        connection.Close();
     }

    return Exists;
 }
```

and important thing to note is do not forget the close the connection finally by calling `connection.Close()`, otherwise it might cause eating up the resources that shouldn't happen when we are done with querying the database and we should release the resources occupied.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to c#.  if you return before the finally{conn.close}, will the method ever reach the finally statement?  I've always been under the impression that a return statement ends the function.

Comment: You should return at end of method, @Mwspencer updated accordingly

Comment: Thank you, I think my logic was off.

Comment: @Mwspencer that's fine `bool` is alias for `Boolean`